# How to create a thick spiral then extract the coordinates from the image?

Tags: plotting

___________________ **FOLLOWUP TO THE QUESTION :** _____________________

Does anyone know how I could quantify the thickness of the spiral AND the thickness of the empty space between the arms? I know that right now it depends on the value put into the `AbsoluteThickness`, but I need to be able to put in a number in, say, nanometers. Does anyone have any ideas on this might be done?

________________________**END OF FOLLLOWUP**__________________

I can plot a thin spiral using just:

$ r=\frac{\theta }{2 \pi };$

```
PolarPlot[theta/2 Pi,{theta,0,2 Pi}]
```

but is there a way to plot a spiral that has actual area (**not just a visually thicker line**, but actual 2D spiral as if you took a long rectangle and curled it up, if that makes sense...)? Like these:
[image]

Essentially, I'm trying to bounce a beam of light off a lens which has this pattern machined out of it, so I need to be able to modify the thickness of the trenches to see how much light will get reflected. The beam of light is estimated as a matrix of points. So I need to have this pattern also represented as a matrix.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "convert the set of points that makes up such a spiral into a 2D array"?

Comment: @march, PolarPlot creates a list of points of the type (r, theta), I need to take that list and convert it into type (x,y)

Comment: This caused me to experiment with drawing random spiral galaxies. Thanks for the diversion!

Comment: do you mean just `PolarPlot[theta/2 Pi, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[8], CapForm["Round"]}, 
    Axes -> None] // Binarize // ImageData // MatrixPlot` ? by setting large ImageSize you can increase the resolution. you can also use `Position[imagedata,1]` and `ImageValuePositions[im,1]` for coordinates

Comment: @amr. By *far* the simplest solution. I recommend posting it as an answer.

Comment: Regarding the spacing/interval update in your question, it's not clear to me what the simplest approach to that is, and there's a couple mathematical issues (eg the spirals are close together at the center). Maybe figuring out how to make alternating black/white spirals that are exactly touching would be a good heuristic. The quickest way might actually be to ask on the Math.SE site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code I posted in my comment above:

```
plot = PolarPlot[theta/2 Pi, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> None,
 PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[8], CapForm["Round"]}];

plot // Binarize // ImageData // MatrixPlot
```

[image: pixelated spiral]

I left it at low resolution, but you can just increase the Graphics `ImageSize` to get very good precision. Though you'd probably want to use Thickness like other posters here did rather than AbsoluteThickness. Since we left the plot in Graphics form you can use Show to get different resolutions without fiddling with the original plot code: `Show[plot, ImageSize -> 1000]`.

Many of the image processing functions automatically `Rasterize` Graphics expressions, such as `Binarize` in this case. Other potentially relevant functions: `Positions`, `ImageValuePositions`, `PixelValuePositions`, `ImageValue`, `ImageLevels`, `SkeletonTransform`, `ImageCrop`.

---

**Update** in response to comment below: To keep {0,0} centered I used the Plot's own `PlotRange` setting and extended it. This centers it in the `Graphics` before rasterizing.

```
plot = PolarPlot[theta/(2 Pi), {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> None,
   PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[8], CapForm["Round"]}];

centerize[plot_Graphics, center_: {0, 0}, options___] :=
  Module[{plotRangeSettings, plotRange, fourCorners, furthest, symmetricPlotRange},

   (*isolate numeric plot range*)
   plotRangeSettings = ReplaceList[PlotRange, Options[plot]];
   plotRange = First[Cases[plotRangeSettings, {{_?NumberQ, _}, {_, _}}]];

   (*pick out furtherst corner and symmetrize its coordinates*)
   fourCorners = Tuples[plotRange];
   furthest = First[MaximalBy[fourCorners, EuclideanDistance[#, center] &]];
   symmetricPlotRange = Sort /@ Transpose[{-furthest, furthest}];(*convert to {{xmin,xmax},{ymin,ymax}}*)

   Show[plot, options, PlotRange -> symmetricPlotRange]];

centerize[plot] // Binarize // ImageData // MatrixPlot
```

[image: centered spiral]

You can see the centering by including the axes:

```
centerize[plot, {0, 0}, ImageSize -> 800, Axes -> True, Ticks -> None] // Binarize // ImageData // MatrixPlot
```

[image: centered spiral with axes]

Comment: I copy pasted your code and for some reason my picture come out with colors inverted >.> ... do you know why that might be? Also, I tried making the spiral bigger (`plot=PolarPlot[theta/2 Pi,{theta,0,4 Pi},Axes->None,PlotStyle->{AbsoluteThickness[55],CapForm["Round"]},ImageSize->{500,500}];`) , but it cropped the edges, how I do make it so it fits the whole thing into a square image?

Comment: @Solarmew no problemos. i'm guessing `Binarize` is choosing a different background based on some threshold, or something like that. Just use `ColorNegate` to get the polarity you need. For the cropping issue you could adjust the PlotRange but the easiest is to set a padding: `PlotRangePadding -> 3`. By the way, you can do something like `ComposeList[{Binarize, ColorNegate, ImageData, MatrixPlot}, 
  plot] // Column` to follow these kinds of sequential transformations.

Comment: Just as an addendum, `ImageCrop[image]` is useful for cutting back exactly after over-padding (such as with PlotRangePadding in this case).

Comment: I'm still confused as to how to get the spiral to start at the origin >.> ... I'm using PlotRangePadding -> Automatic and that seems to be working well as far as not cropping the edges and not creating extra space, but I'd rather have extra space if that means the spiral is centered. And by centered I mean that it STARTS unwinding at the origin, not the picture itself is centered.

Comment: I'm currently busy but I'll see if I can figure something out later today. In any case, feel free to re-accept to someone else's answer.

Comment: @Solarmew See my edit for one solution to that.

Answer (score 6):

```
parm = CoordinateTransform["Polar" -> "Cartesian", {u/2 Pi, u}];
n = {#2, -#1} & @@ (Normalize@D[parm, u]);
ParametricPlot[{{r n + parm}, {parm}}, {u, 0, 10 Pi}, {r, -1.5, 1.5}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{{u^2 /400 r n + parm}, {parm}}, {u, 0, 
  10 Pi}, {r, -1.5, 1.5}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Update July 14: Fixed Centering of Positions**

Here is a summary of the code:

```
image = Graphics[{
  Thickness[0.03]
  , CapForm["Round"]
  , Line[Table[
     theta/(2 Pi) {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}
     , {theta, 0, 20 Pi, 20 Pi/599}
    ]]
  , RGBColor[1., 0., 0.], AbsolutePointSize[1], Point[{0, 0}]
 }
 , ImageSize -> {100, 100}
]
centralPosition = Position[ImageData @ image, {1., 0., 0.}];
array = ReplacePart[1 - MorphologicalComponents@image, First@centralPosition -> 1];
positions = ComponentMeasurements[array, "Mask"][[1, 2]]["NonzeroPositions"];
shiftedPositions = # - First@centralPosition & /@ positions;
```

To make it so that the image spirals out from the actual origin, I placed a red pixel right at the center of the image. We then use `ImageData`, which returns an array of color data for each pixel. We find the `Position` of the red pixel, add this point back into the `array`, and shift the `positions` by the position of the red pixel. As shown in the third figure below, this makes it so that the origin is at the center of the spiral.

Again: you can change the `ImageSize` to be whatever you wish. Increasing it yields better resolution. In addition, increasing the number of points in the `Table` that defines the spiral might help. Finally, I have used `Thickness[0.03]` so that the thickness of the spiral is always 3% of the figure size.

*Generating the images below.* The first image is just `image`. The third and fourth images are, respectively,

```
MatrixPlot[array, ImageSize -> 250]
MatrixPlot[1 - array, ImageSize -> 250]
```

Finally, to generate the second figure, we have to get the positions of both the spiral and the negative of the spiral and assign to the positions the values 1 or 0 depending on whether they're in the spiral or not. To get the negative:

```
inversePositions = ComponentMeasurements[1 - array, "Mask"][[1, 2]]["NonzeroPositions"];
shiftedInversePositions = # - First@centralPosition & /@ inversePositions;
```

Finally, to get the list of coordinates with values, we do

```
finalArray = Join[
  Flatten@{#, 1} & /@ shiftedPositions
  , Flatten@{#, 0} & /@ shiftedInversePositions
];
```

and to plot it, we do

```
ListDensityPlot[finalArray
 , InterpolationOrder -> 0
 , Axes -> True
 , ImageSize -> 250]
```

This last takes a little bit of time, and will take longer and longer the bigger the original image, so be careful.

[image]

**Original Post**

Here's how I would go about doing drawing the spirals.

```
image = Graphics[{
  AbsoluteThickness[10]
  , CapForm["Round"]
  , Line[Table[
      theta/(2 Pi) {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}
      , {theta, 0, 20 Pi, 20 Pi/599}
    ]]
 }
 ,ImageSize -> {500, 500}
]
```

Changing the argument of `AbsoluteThickness[20]` allows you to get different thicknesses. Changing the number of points in the `Line` makes it look nicer as well. The `"Round"` `Capform` makes the ends of the `Line` look nice. This particular code results in

[image]

(**Update**: there was an error in the original post. `Image Size` should be `ImageSize`, and since this was wrong, it used the default width of 360 instead.) We set the `ImageSize` in order to determine how many points there are in the image. For instance, taking `ImageSize -> {500, 400}` makes the grid have a width of 500 points and a height of 400 points. You can change this to, say, 1000 by 1000, but you will need to change the `AbsoluteThickness` argument, because the thickness won't scale with the size of the image. If you want it to, you can use `Thickness` instead, and the argument will be the fraction of the image width that the line takes up.

Now, to get the $(x,y)$ components, we can first call `MorphologicalComponents` on the image to get a matrix of 1's where there is black and 0's where there is white as

```
array = 1 - MorphologicalComponents @ image;
```

Finally, we extract the positions via

```
positions = ComponentMeasurements[array, "Mask"][[1, 2]]["NonzeroPositions"];
```

`ComponentMeasurements[array, "Mask"][[1, 2]]` returns a `SparseArray` object, and we use the `SparseArray` method `"NonzeroPositions"` to extract the positions at which the image `array` is non-zero, which is where the original image is black.

If we plot `array` using

```
MatrixPlot[array]
```

we get the figure below, and the coordinates of the orange positions are in the list `positions`.

**Update** If you need to shift the positions so that the original center of the spiral is at the origin, do the following. If your grid is 500 by 400, say, then do:

```
shiftedPositions = {-501/2, -401/2} + # & /@ positions;
```

This takes the shift `{-501/2,-401/2}` and adds it to every element in the list by constructing the pure function `{-501/2, -401/2} + # &` and `Map`ing it (shorthand: `/@`) over the list `positions`, which applies the pure function to every element of the list.

[image]

Comment: but this just makes it LOOK thicker, doesn't it? ... If you plot this in cartesian coordinates and pick a point (x,y) somewhere in the middle of a black region, there AREN'T actually points immediately all around it (x±ɛ, y±ɛ), even though it looks like there are. I would like to be able to construct a matrix out if this graph where if the graph is white, the point is 0, otherwise it's 1.

Comment: @Solarmew. Oh I see! I misunderstood. We might be able to kluge something together using image processing stuff in Mathematica by taking the image that is generated and *finding* the points that are black, but I'm a novice at best with that stuff. We need to use `MorphologicalComponents`. How many points do you want in the image?

Comment: @Solarmew. I've updated the answer with one possibility for getting what you want. Please take a look, and we can fine-tune it as needed! By the way, it would be useful to edit the body *and title* of your original question to include the information about getting the (x,y) coordinates in your comment above. Making the lines thicker is not a very difficult question, but getting the (x,y) coordinates of the spiral is a *very* interesting question, and probably useful to many people.

Comment: wow, very fancy :] I believe this will work! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Solarmew. Thank you for the accept! But it is a good idea to wait at least a couple of days to accept the answer, because that motivates others to chime in with their own takes. There are many gifted Mathematica users on this site, and I'm sure that someone could come up with something simpler, more straight-forward, and more elegant than my answer. Feel free to "un-accept" if you'd like to spur more answers (but make sure to edit your title and question with more about what you want in order to get more people interested).

Comment: alright, I'll see if anyone else would like to pitch in :] I feel bad un-accepting tho :(

Comment: @Solarmew. No problem! This site is for getting good answers to questions, not getting points, and the accepted answers tend to be viewed more than non-accepted ones, so it's important to accept the best one.

Comment: is there any way to shift the image (or the array of points from it) so that it's centered at the origin?

Comment: @Solarmew. I updated the answer with the answers to your questions: (1) there was an error in the code (`ImageSize`), (2) an explanation for how the image size works, and (3) how to shift the position list so that the center is at the origin.

Comment: hm, now that I finally got around to it, I don't think I explained what I meant  by "centered" spiral very well. I meant that I wanted it to start unwinding from the origin, not that the picture itself is centered >.< ... Do you have any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: @Solarmew. No, you explained it correctly; I just implemented it naively (and incorrectly). Unfortunately, I don't know how to shift the positions correctly once you have the position list. Instead, I have updated my answer with a way to get the correct shifted positions starting from the beginning. Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems to be working, but I can't get the axes to display. It's just the spiral right now. I tried `MatrixPlot` but it didn't work +.+ How do I get the axes and  values to show up? Also, is there any way to keep the image from blowing up when you increase image size? As in, have it stay the same size on the screen, just improve resolution. Probably not, huh? Because here we're using a discrete number of points.

Comment: @Solarmew. See the updated post. To display the images smaller on the screen, you can always wrap the assignments in `Show`. For example, `Show[image = Graphics[<code>], ImageSize -> 200]`. Just make sure the assignments are inside `Show`, as I've shown. Otherwise, it will overwrite the actual `ImageSize` in the image.

Answer (score 5):

Another way will be to simply take advantage of the `CapForm` primitives and get those rounded lines. I am using a transformation rule on the `Graphics` object generated by the `PolarPlot` function to change the default lines into a rounded one.

```
plot=PolarPlot[theta/2 Pi, {theta, 0, 20 Pi},Axes->None,PlotStyle->Black, PlotRange -> All];
plot/.Line[point_] :> {CapForm["Round"],Thickness[.03],Line[point]}
```

[image]

**Update:**
An accurate way to address the following requirement!

> "I need to have this pattern also represented as a matrix"

1. First discretize the 2D line plot of the spiral and form a region distance function based on that discrete curve.
2. Sample a good number of points on the $\{x,y\}$ plane where the spiral lies.
3. Use the region distance function to mark only those points which satisfy you trench thickness criterion.

Here is the commented code to generate the requested matrix:

```
reg=DiscretizeGraphics@plot;(* Step 1: Discretize 2D *)
df = RegionDistance[reg]; (* Step 1: Distance function *)
(* Step 3: Sample point but extend the bounding box by {-4, +4} *)
samplePt=Outer[List, ##] & @@ (Range[##, .8] & @@@ (# + {-4, +4} &/@RegionBounds[reg]));
(* Get your image matrix! TRENCH Thickness = 2 *)
ImageData@ImageRotate@Image@Map[If[df[#] <= 2., 1., 0.] &,samplePt, {2}]
```

Image looks like this.

[image]

Here goes a visualization of the 2D spiral mesh and the generated $19415$ points on the Cartesian plane with an Euclidean distance of utmost $2$ units from the spiral. One can generate less points by choosing coarser (>0.8) sampling in `Range[##, .8]`. Code follows after the image.

[image]

```
Show[Graphics@{PointSize@Tiny, Orange,Point/@ 
(If[df[#] <= 2, #, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]] & /@ Flatten[samplePt,1])},
HighlightMesh[reg, Style[1, Opacity[.7], Red]]]
```